# Do I have a censored variable or not? What is the mean of my data?

Tags: r, logistic, mean, binomial-distribution, tobit-regression

I have a variable variable from a survey, which has a range from never (0) to always (100) in 10 steps (0 -100). It is obviously a discrete (ordinal) variable, but I want to try to treat is as continuous (or at least not ordinal), because I want to aggregate this variable to the `area` level. I want to aggregate them to the `area` level, to be able to run a panel regression at the `area` level. (In other words, I want to use the mean value of this variable for each area as a variable in my actual regression). The ultimate goal, is to treat the mean as an endogenous variable in panel data and use an IV approach to examine how changes to the mean of this variable relate to changes in the dependent variable.

I am conflicted on how to aggregate the data. If I insist on treating it as a discrete, how should I determine the mean by `area`? I started out with just taking the "normal" mean, but I thought that distribution wise, my data is censored. Because it can take on only values between 0 and 100 (Although the range of interpretation goes from always to never). In case the data is censored, taking the mean would underestimate the mean of the "latent" variable.

I have also been considering using a logistic regression because I read it also works for values between 0 and 1, which would perhaps be a good approximation for my data which ranges from 0-100 with values in between.

In the end, I am unsure how to calculate the mean, considering the distribution of the data. I know that calculating the mean for censored data is quite troublesome (and I do not know how to do it ([link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/512448/aggregating-taking-the-mean-of-a-censored-variable)). Is the mean of a logistic distribution simply the "normal" mean?

```
# dat represents the first 100 values
dat <- c(100, 55.55, 100, 100, 88.88, 100, 100, 100, 66.66, 100, 100, 
100, 0, 100, 55.55, 100, 100, 100, 100, 88.88, 100, 88.88, 88.88, 
100, 0, 88.88, 100, 100, 100, 88.88, 100, 100, 33.33, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 33.33, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 66.66, 100, 88.88, 100, 88.88, 
100, 44.44, 88.88, 77.77, 100, 100, 100, 55.55, 100, 88.88, 100, 
88.88, 55.55, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
55.55, 88.88, 100, 100, 66.77, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
55.55, 100, 100, 88.88, 100, 100, 22.22, 77.77)
area <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A")
dat <- cbind(dat, area)
```

[image]

Taking the normal mean, by `area`, results in the following:

[image]

Comment: "Numerically, my data is obviously censored" misunderstands censoring.  You appear to have *ordinal,* discrete data on a 10 point scale.  That's all.  Indeed, censoring would correspond to situations less rare than "never" and more frequent than "always."  Thus, you might be asking the wrong questions.  Could you explain *why* the mean of the values might be of interest?  How do you hope that will help you make a decision, take an action, or understand something?  How is this variable related to the logistic regression you contemplate?

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment, which showed me I made a very poorly phrased and confusing question. I have made an attempt to clear and clean up the question a bit. I would be super happy if you would be willing to take another look at it.

Comment: whuber's question "How do you hope that will help you make a decision, take an action, or understand something?" has only a very poor answer in the edited version: " to be able to run a regression at the area level."

Comment: @Bernhard Is it better like this? If not, could you elaborate on what I should add?

Comment: For one, I do not see, why computing a mean poses a problem, once you decided to use the data as quasi-metric.Second: Whether data that is constrained to a certain range should be tackled via logistic or binomial or ... regression will depend heavily on whether that variable is an in dependent or dependend variable, a $y$ or an $x$.